# Messed up pgAdmin 4 menu bar

Tags: windows, pgadmin-4

I would like to know how to load the default setting for pgAdmin-4. I messed up with the menu bar and now I cannot see the tree view. I tried re-installing it but still loading the same setting. I posted a screenshot for reference.

[image: messed-up pgAdmin4 menu bar]

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved after doing a thorough uninstall.

1. Removed files associated with pgAdmin from the Local and Roaming folders located at c:\Users\Username\Appdata
2. Removed files associated with pgAdmin from registry including HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software, HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE & HKEY_USERS.DEFAULT\Software

Answer (score 0):

You will simply need to restore default layout settings. This will solve the problem however, you will need to save and close all open codes.

[image]