# pgAdmin 4 (Mac): I Lost My Tree Where I Can Access My Servers

Tags: macos, macos-sierra, pgadmin-4

Earlier today I was able to view my server tree. I clicked something I supposed before I closed the application. I thought that maybe something else happened so I cleaned my Mac Mini Server. I still had the problem along with none of the dropdown windows displaying any entries. When I click the elephant at the top left a window opens with no text and two buttons for Ok and Cancel.

[image]

I found this link [Messed up pgAdmin 4 menu bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43818620/messed-up-pgadmin-4-menu-bar) where the person had a similar problem running Windows. I used the information on this link and attempted to do the equivalent actions on my Mac. I moved the ~/Library/Application Support/pgAdmin folder then the application (v 4.1.5) to the trash and emptied the trash. I still have the problem. I also tried to go to my backups from last night to restore the application and the ~/Library/Application Support/pgAdmin folder. I still have the problem.

With all of my searching all I could find about the menu bar is the link above and the documentation link on the pgAdmin about the menu bar. Nothing about how to solve this problem. I could not find any plist related to pgAdmin. I don't know where to go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try deleting following directory and restart pgAdmin4 again.

> ~/.pgadmin

Comment: That fixed it. I knew there had to be another file with pgadmin info somewhere. I did a search for pgadmin but it did not appear since this is a hidden file I guess. I will remember next time!

Comment: but after delete the folder, will lost all yours registered servers

Comment: @FrankNStein you can export you server before deleing https://www.pgadmin.org/docs/pgadmin4/3.6/export_import_servers.html#exporting-and-importing-servers