# How to enable pgAdmin (4.4) Menu Bars

Tags: pgadmin-4

Tried starting pgAdmin 4.1, observed that the menu bar came out as shown in the image below:

[image: pgAdmin interface without menu bars]

Had followed this guide on SO: [Messed up pgAdmin 4 menu bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43818620/messed-up-pgadmin-4-menu-bar). Then uninstalled v.4.1. I now have v.4.4 installed but got same display.

Also, I can't get the object menu bar dropdown to work. Clicking it produces no response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't try opening the site using different web browsers (silly me). I had been using the default, Firefox Developer Edition.

Opening the pgAdmin web interface with Edge and Chrome opened it just fine. The error is specific to Firefox Developer Edition.

Comment: Yes it is due to Cache, may be the Javascript files from the older version is still present in Firefox browser cache, you can try clearing browser cache.

Answer (score 0):

You need to hard reload page, Remove the browser cache & try again.

For example in Google Chrome, Right click on the refresh button and select Empty Cache and Hard Reload

[image]

Open pgAdmin4 again & Check if that helps.

Comment: I don't have this right-click refresh button in my Chrome v73.0.3683.103. However opening the site in Chrome helped. I was using Firefox Developer Edition as default browser so the error is specific to Firefox Developer Edition. Edge and Chrome opened it just fine.